# Installing program on Linux Mint - Root password not accepted

Tags: linux, passwords, linux-mint, root

I just installed Linux for the first time and really want to like it, but just spend over two hours trying to figure out how to install Inkscape.

I finally figured out that I need to go to "software manager" - that was my fault for assuming things would be the same as windows.

However, when I click install for Inkscape, I am prompted to enter the root password. I entered the password for my user, but it is rejected. I only set one password when I installed Linux Mint (cinnamon) and can log into the only account just fine with it. That leaves me confused and frustrated that I can't do something as simple as instal a program after excitedly jumping into an operating system that I have been wanting to try for some time.

From the terminal I am also denied root permission.

I apologize if the answer is simple, but I spent a lot of time looking for any insights about this, and it might simply be that I don't know what terms to search for.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the results of `sudo -l`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to successfully switch to the root user from the command line yet? You would run something like this to do that:

```
sudo su - root
```

I’m not a regular Mint user, but from what I’m reading about it, Mint might not have a root password set for you by default. So when you log in as root for the first time at the command line it might ask you to set the password yourself. Then I’d bet Software Center would accept it.

Alternatively (and I’d actually recommend doing it this way) you can totally install things directly from the command line via the built in `apt` package manager. That’s the way most people will do it anyway.  I think Software Center actually uses this behind the scenes too but I’m not sure.

To do that:

First update apt’s package definitions, sources, metadata, and such:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Second, install Inkscape:

```
sudo apt-get install inkskape
```

Then you should be able to launch it through your desktop like you’d hope and expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response - I tried:  sudo us - root.
      After putting in the user password I am denied access: Sorry, MyUser is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - root' as root on MyComputer

Comment: I should add that I followed some tutorials on how to grant the user permission to communicate through serial port (I am making a project Arduino). I don't see why this would have removed root permissions, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Based on what I've read, when you install Mint and it asks you to set your user account password, it is supposed to quietly set the same password for root, but it sounds like that might not have happened.  To use the `sudo` command, your user needs to be in the `sudo` group.  Try running `su - root` to switch to the root user (giving your user's password). Then (from root) try `usermod -aG sudo myuser` to add yourself to the sudo group.  (Replace "myuser" with your user account name).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tired the command and got "Permission denied" 
I think I just need to reload the operating system, something went wrong because it does not appear that there is an obvious answer as to why the only user on the computer lost sudo permissions.